# How to use md-chips in line

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to use the md-chips directive of angular material in a single line, but when I add more chips than size of a field, the field add a line to bottom like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNhyR.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a CSS workaround to adapt the behaviour of [md-chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips) in an input form.

For example you can use this CSS:

```
/* reduce input element (not visible till the user begins editing) width */
.md-chips .md-chip-input-container input {
  max-width: 20px;
}

 /* adapt input to md-chip height */
.myheight {
  height: 49px !important;
}

/* adapt datepicker input to md-chip height */
.md-datepicker-input {
  height: 49px;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/gPqPBW

P.S.: don't forget that docs declare:

> Warning: This component is a WORK IN PROGRESS. If you use it now, it will probably break on you in the future.

Comment: In your example, the component does not show what are being write and when the space limit of the line is reached they create a new line below, the behavior that i want to avoid to create a new line below and continue in the same line hiding the firsts 'tags' that are in the left.


thanks for your help

Comment: Probably to obtain what you desire you need another component. This one has an 'invisible' input element and has no horizontal scroll for chips already in

Comment: to show multiple chips inline: `<md-chips ng-model="['Apples','Oranges']" readonly></md-chips>`