# Angular material md-chips md-autocomplete

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete, md-chip

How do you prevent the input line from expanding when you add multiple chips. I've tried setting the flex and width but it ends up pushing the input line downwards. I've also tried setting it to absolute but that completely messed up the alignment. Here is a picture of what is happening:

[Example of md-chip with autocomplete with input box acting weird.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBtkM.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use md-chips in line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353358/how-to-use-md-chips-in-line)

Comment: Thanks I saw that example. I'm unable to see the view in the code pen. But it's slightly different. I'm trying to prevent the input line form expanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `max-width`, `max-height` and `overflow-x: hidden` to `md-chips-wrap` tag in your CSS file.

Something like this:

```
md-chips-wrap{
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And let me know if it is ok for you!

Comment: thanks it works ok but now I can' see the chips at all. unless I use the scroll bar. I think the placeholder is blocking it I guess the input box has to move eventually when you add a lot of chips. It just shouldn't look really messy if you get what I'm saying

Comment: Hi @ Patrick lucka can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41509407/6480245