# md-chips and md-autocomplete input field

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete, md-chip

When user enters an input with md-chips   and the focus is removed the entry is still there. is there a way to delete any entry that is not a chip once the focus is removed?
[The Out Standing Text still shows once the focus is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ8Ke.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should be able to do it by using `ng-blur` but for some reason there is an issue with that directive in use with `md-autocomplete`: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3906

But i tried to solve it differently, not the most correct way, but it works. What you have to do is bind event with `blur` in `input` inside `md-autocomplete`. In this event you have to clear your searchText of md-autocomplete. So just bind that event in your controller somehow like that:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('md-autocomplete input')).bind('blur', 
    function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            angular.element(document.querySelector('md-autocomplete')).scope().ctrl.searchText = ''; 
            angular.element(document.querySelector('md-autocomplete')).scope().$apply();
        }, 300);
    }
)
```

The reason why I used timeout was the fact that chip was not added if searchText variable was cleared too fast. But when I added 300ms delay it worked as I expected. For sure there is better way to do it, but just try to do it this way and maybe it will be enough for you.

Here is working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdNydx

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patryk. It doesn't seem to be working. the function never gets called in my controller. I'm thinking it may be because I'm using controller As syntax. vm = this; so when I replaced ctrl.searchText with my vm.searchText it doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Try to experiment in your browser console. Try to use ` angular.element(document.querySelector('md-autocomplete')).scope()` and check in which variable is your controller and make sure you have correct search text variable

Comment: And also, if you attach your code it will be easier to help you : ) plunkr, codepen or jsfiddle would help even more

Comment: I have attached it to the original post

Comment: If you can see correct value in your browsers console after typing "angular.element(document.querySelector('md-autocomplete')).scope().containerVisibility.searchLoadId" then I don't know how to help you : ( this is the only place where I think there might be something wrong... especially that "containerVisibility" looks pretty weird, but I believe that you checked it. Or maybe try to create plunker, jsfiddler or something like that with that problem? I don't see anything wrong by just reading your code...

Comment: I have just thought that maybe your binding is done before the template is fully rendered? Try to use that binding function in some different way... i don't want advice you to use another timeout (but it could work...), but maybe some kind of activation function or any other that you call after rendering?

Comment: Ok, and I forgot about scope.$apply to make it work correctly. Here is working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdNydx

Comment: Thanks I will test it out

Comment: Worked Perfectly Thanks a lot! If I can find a better way to do this I will fix it  but for now it does the job!

Comment: ng-blur seems to work when you add data infront of it. data-ng-blur