# How to make md-chips overflow horizontally?

Tags: html, css, angularjs-material, md-chip

When exceeding the length of the input, the md-chips creates a new line. I'd like the chips to continue always in one single line and the input to overflow horizontally just as a normal text input. How to achieve this? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353358/how-to-use-md-chips-in-line) is not working for me.

Image of the undesired behavior:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a codepen on what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking about `angularjs-material` or `angular-material (angular2/4)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to overflow chips with pure css, you can do the following: ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/oFalj8?p=preview))

**HTML**

```
<md-chips class="chips-overflow" placeholder="Enter an animal..."></md-chips>
```

**CSS**

```
.chips-overflow .md-chips {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.chips-overflow .md-chips md-chip, 
.chips-overflow .md-chips .md-chip-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

---

** *This will work perfectly with **angularjs-material version >= 1.1.0**, and it works but will have problems with placeholder with **angularjs-material version >= 0.0.9***

Comment: Obviously, you don't have overflow like angularjs material tabs, this will be the browser horizontal scrollbar. To do something like that you have to add two arrows icons with fixed position and when the user click  it, use [javascript scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) to move the scroll programatically. Additionally, you will have to hide the horizontal bar with some css trick. As you see is not an easy task... I hope my answer is enough for you

Comment: That actually worked. I just needed to adapt the container so the chips would overflow within it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: saved my time and energy :)